# How to handle input type=file with jQuery click event on another element

Tags: jquery

I've this code

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="u-button">Upload Photo</div>
    <form id="u_form" action="upload.php" method="post" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_t">
       <input id="upload" type="file" name="img" class="multi"/>
       <iframe id="upload_t" class="hide" name="upload_t" src=""></iframe>
    </form>
</div>
```

The `div#main` is set to height and width similar to `div#u-button` and set overflow to hidden.
The idea is to hide the form. I do not want the default file upload input element's style so what I'm trying to do is, on clicking on `div#u-button`, I want it to fire the click event on `input#upload`.

My jQuery codes is like

```
$('#u-button').live('click', function(){ $("#upload").click(); });
```

This seem to work with some browsers (newer versions of all browsers) but in some older browsers, it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me tweak the codes to make it work on more browser versions?

Comment: Perhaps more specification on the version of browser where this does not work would help ?

Comment: which jquery version do you use ?

Comment: jQuery 1.5 (jquery-1.5.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire an event of an element use the jQuery command `trigger()`.

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

You probably tried to hide the `input#upload` as `display=none` or `visbilty:hidden`. This would break the click event in older browser for security reason.

Try to make `#upload` not hidden. You can make your `u-button` higher `z-index`, and `position:absolute`, so the div can cover `#unload`.

Or make your unload button `position:absolute`, and push it off the screen with `top: -10000px`.